# What is the point of defining actions within intent filters on a reciever tag

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm currently exploring Broadcast Receivers and Broadcast Intent.  There are some aspects of the tutorials which are ambiguous to me.  To my knowledge this is how the process works.  I can broadcast an intent from my application and any receiver on the phone can act on that intent as long as the actions match.  I can register a broadcaster receiver on anything that extends Context and when I do so I must provide a filter which will allow the receiver to act on one or more intent actions.

The part which confuses me is defining a receiver via the manifest.  Must the name of said receiver match a class name?  Why should I ever define an intent filter with an action in the project manifest if I always have to provide another intent filter when I register my receiver in code?

If anyone has a good tutorial or example of the best way to use broadcast receivers and how I should define them I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant broadcast an intent from my
>   application and any receiver on the
>   phone can act on that intent as long
>   as the actions match.

Yes, you can.

> Must the name of said receiver match a
>   class name?

Yes, because that is the class that implements the `BroadcastReceiver`.

> Why should I ever define an intent
>   filter with an action if whenever I
>   register a receiver I have to provide
>   an intent filter?

That sentence makes no sense.

Here are [some examples](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot/) of projects using [manifest-registered](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnWiFiChange/) `BroadcastReceivers` whose `<intent-filter>` filters on an [action](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/).

Comment: @CommonsWare Let me rephrase that last question.  Why should I ever define an intent filter with an action in the project manifest if I always have to provide another intent filter when I register my receiver in code?  

I'll look through the examples you provided.  Thanks for the feed back.

Comment: "Why should I ever define an intent filter with an action in the project manifest if I always have to provide another intent filter when I register my receiver in code?" A `BroadcastReceiver` can be registered *either* through the manifest or through Java code. There is no "another" -- any given `BroadcastReceiver` will use one of the two techniques, not both. You use a manifest-registered receiver in cases where it is required by the SDK (e.g., for `BOOT_COMPLETED`) or where you need to respond to `Intents` without any other component running (e.g., for a scheduled alarm).

Comment: So you're saying that if I register a receiver via the manifest it will load and run onReceive regardless of my applications state?  I don't have to register it with a service or activity?

Comment: From looking at your example I see that my previous comment is true.  Thank you for teaching me how powerful a tool receivers are and for providing clarity on the topic.

Comment: Note that there are some broadcasts that are not supported with manifest-registered receivers. `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is one. In those cases, they happen often enough that Android does not want to start up processes just to tell you that, say, the battery level changed.